# Get json response when uploading image with Froala

Tags: froala

I can upload an image with Froala but I don't find the way to get the "pk" parameter I sent with the response. The imageInsert callback doesn't look to be usefull. How can I use the real callback of ImageUpload?
Here is my code in django:

```
class ArticleImageUploadView(CreateView):
    form_class = ArticleUploadImageForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ArticleImageUploadView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error':_('There was a problem processing your image. Please try again')}), content_type="application/json")


    def form_valid(self, form):
        #image = form.save(commit=False)
        article_image = form.save(commit=False)
        if "article_id" in self.request.POST:
            article_image.article_id = self.request.POST.get("article_id")
        article_image.save()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'link':article_image.image.url,'pk':article_image.pk}), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to st3fan for the new feature which do what I need

https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/348

Answer (score 1):

Currently the editor doesn't has any option for what you're asking, but I would suggest opening a feature request on https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor and probably it will be implemented pretty soon.

Comment: It's waht I thought. I asked here just in case. I will open a ticket. Thank you